# User Form Multi Page Control - Page Caption Left Alignment

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I was searching everywhere on the Net, and couldn't find a result if it is possible to align the Multi-Page Control (on a User Form)  Page Caption to the left (see image below).

I want that all pages caption will be aligned to the left - now it doesn't look so when they are aligned center (visually).

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the properties page set **TabOrientation to 2 - frmTabOrientationOnLeft**

I didn't like how the tabs look (Second Form) so I changed **Style to 1- frmTabStyleButtons**.  You can also change the Tab Height and Width from here.

I miss read the question.  There is not a text alignment for tab captions. But this will effectively give you the look of left alignment:

- Using a monospace font (Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console, Monaco)
- Add extra spaces to the end of each caption until each caption has the same amount of characters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of these options. I just want that all Caption text for all 5 pages will be aligned to the left. is it possible somehow by VBA ? because I couldn't find any property in the Object Properties in the VB Editor.

Comment: Sorry about that. I misread the question.  I updated my answer with a workaround for the alignment problem.

Comment: That's what I found so far, was hoping maybe I missed something. I already tried the extra spaces at the end a few days ago, but it's not giving a consistant result, sometime the text jumps back to the right.

Comment: @ThomasInzina doesn't work unfortunately... tried it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `vbTab`at the end of your caption strings. In my example I've used `TabFixedWidth`property with a value of 90. For a shorter caption as for page 3 it's necessary to insert `vbTab`twice. For a longer Caption as for page 7 no `vbTab`is needed.

```
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg1").Caption = "1 Overview" & vbTab
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg2").Caption = "2 Tables" & vbTab
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg3").Caption = "3 Forms" & vbTab & vbTab
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg4").Caption = "4 Databases" & vbTab
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg5").Caption = "5 Reports" & vbTab
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg6").Caption = "6 Examples" & vbTab
mpgBid.Pages.Item("pg7").Caption = "7 More Examples"
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQxUG.jpg)